# How can I rename a Ruby library module's namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I'd like to use the [ruby Stripe library](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby) in a Rails app. It uses the module `Stripe` as its namespace.

I want to use `Stripe` as the namespace for my ActiveRecord models, and rename the library module to something like StripeApi, so that e.g. `StripeApi::Charge` refers to the Stripe library, but `Stripe::Charge` refers to my `Stripe`-namespaced ActiveRecord model (so that e.g. `Stripe::Charge.create(...)` creates a database record, rather than just making API calls).

Is there a good way to do this?

(Sure, I could rename my namespace, or try to use differently named models, but I find that kinda ugly.)

Comment: Really, you find renaming your own namespace ugly and gem's namespace ok? Really?

Comment: Perhaps I just can't think of a non-ugly name for it. What would you suggest?

Comment: What does your model do?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel It's part of a number of similar ones (e.g. for PayPal, Stripe, Google Wallet, Amazon Checkout) that basically mirrors everything in the API, so I have it stored local to the server. Necessary for auditing purposes (my company is federally regulated) as well as for easier aggregation / normalization / etc for accounting and taking advantage of some advanced functionality in each. Each of them is namespaced (/app/models/paypal/ etc).

Comment: What about simply extending existing Stripe class with your method as in Facade pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really recommend to rename your own namespace since you have full control over the code.
Otherwise it could really become a pain in the ass if you want to update the version of the Stripe gem or search for a Bug relating to your namespace as well to the original Stripe namespace.

It's a lot easier to change the own namespace instead of changing an existing gem (eventually for every version again).

Comment: I ended up doing this. Put my stuff under a `Payment::` namespace and left the APIs as they are.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as "namespace" in Ruby. It's just a variable (well, constant):

```
StripeApi = Stripe
```

Boom. You're done.

Make sure to set `Stripe` to a new module, so that you don't accidentally reopen the module when you think you are creating a new one:

```
Stripe = Module.new
```

Now you can do

```
class Stripe::Charge; end
```

Comment: While correct, this is going to break in hilarious ways if the Stripe gem ever references itself via `::Stripe`.

Comment: Chris, in real life there is perhaps one Rubiest who would not use that adjective.