# Use two gems in same namespace in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an app that uses the [LinkedIn](https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin) gem but I need to move towards using the LinkedIn OAuth2 implementation which comes in a [different gem](https://github.com/emorikawa/linkedin-oauth2).

I need to support the requests on oAuth1 in the initial gem for existing users, but I need to support OAuth2 for new users going forwards.

The problem is, both of these gems use the `LinkedIn` namespace for their module names, and depending on what order I include them in my Gemfile, one clobbers the other.

I tried adding `require: false` to the gemfile like so:

```
gem 'linkedin', require: false
gem 'linkedin-oauth2', require: false
```

But weirdly enough when I go to my console, the first one is still being required, where as the second one is not:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'linkedin'
=> false
irb(main):002:0> require 'linkedin-oauth2'
=> true
```

Is this something to do with how require works? Is it possible to load just one of these gems each in separate lib files without clobbering each other?

**EDIT**

I figured out that I was requiring the `linkedin` in one of my spec files, which was causing it to be autoloaded, but that did not still fix the issue of things being clobbered.

When I have both gems installed and I run:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'linkedin'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> ::LinkedIn::Client.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Api::QueryHelpers
        from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/linkedin-1.1.0/lib/linked_in/client.rb:8:in `<class:Client>'
irb(main):004:0> require 'linkedin-oauth2'                                                                                                                                                                                                    
=> true
```

But if I uninstall `linkedin-oauth2` from my gemfile it works just fine:

```
irb(main):002:0> require 'linkedin'
=> true
irb(main):004:0> ::LinkedIn::Client.new
=> #<LinkedIn::Client:0x007f9eef6d72a8 @consumer_token=nil, @consumer_secret=nil, @consumer_options={}>
```

Why is that, especially since `linkedin-oauth2` is not being required in the first example, yet the error occurs. Could it be because of how they [require supporting files](https://github.com/hexgnu/linkedin/blob/master/lib/linked_in/client.rb#L8) in the `linkedin` gem? Seems still like it shouldn't affect it.

Comment: You could either move everything to use the `linkedin-oauth2` gem or go tinker with the gem modules themselves so that the first just extends the second (this is not recommended however because it will still clobber the methods that are named the same).

Comment: _"the first one is still being required"_ – are you sure that you don't `require` it somewhere else?

Comment: @Stefan right you are. I was still requiring it in one of my specs. So I fixed that, but now when I do `require 'linkedin'` it seems to be requiring the `linkedin-oauth2` gem.

Comment: @Stefan I edited the question and added more detail about the issue I am seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, since it could have some weird side effects such as if linkedin-oauth2 references itself with `::LinkedIn`, but a method to redefine a ruby constant is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601198/4133078).

I would change it a little bit to prevent renaming a constant warning... `Object.send(:remove_const, :Stripe)` instead of the `Stripe = Module.new` as shown in the answer. So, an example (not tested) would be:

```
require 'linkedin-oauth2'
LinkedInOauth2 = LinkedIn

Object.send(:remove_const, :LinkedIn)

require 'linkedin'
```